# drawing a 2D-plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-pic

i need to draw this plane, but i don't know how

[image]

can anyone help me? its important i need it in my master report. i try to use this from an old example to start with but it didn't work

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip[draw](48,1) to[closed,curve through={(50,3) .. (52,4) .. (51,6) ..(47,6) .. (46.6,5) .. (45,3.8) }] (48,1);
\node[draw,circle,fill=magenta,minimum width=2cm] (n1) at (50,3) {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. The code you provided uses the `curve through` keyword, which is not standard tikz. Which package comes it from? Anyway, "fixing" it by replacing by a `plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {...}` it results in a figure which is not related to the drawing you pasted. For example, what is the magenta circle?

Comment: Do you need all those fluctuations in the drawing?

Comment: not all of them but at least to be known that there is some fluctuation on the whole boundary in green so you can reduce the number of fluctuation

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

[image: Result]

I used `random steps` decorator for the green path, and "manually" built the black path, using some key points and start/end angles. Also note the use of polar coordinates, which are more appropiate for this case than cartesian ones.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.geometric}
\colorlet{myred}{red!60!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!40!black}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\node[draw=myred, ellipse, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=4.5cm] (e1) {};
\draw[myred, ->] (e1.-30) -- +(-20:2) node[right] {$\Omega_0$};

\node[draw=mygreen, ellipse, minimum width=3.8cm, minimum height=5.2cm,
     decoration={random steps, segment length=1.5mm}, decorate]
     (e2) {};
\draw[mygreen, ->] (e2.0) --  +(5:1.5) node[right] {$\widetilde\Omega_0$};
\draw[mygreen, <-] (e2.90) -- +(80:.5) node[right] {$v_\varepsilon=0$};


\draw (0:3) to[out=90,in=-65]      (45:4)
            to[out=180-65,in=0]    (90:5)
            to[out=180, in=180-70] (150:4.5)
            to[out=-70, in=90]     (190:3.2)
            to[out=-90, in=180-50] (234:5.1)
            to[out=-50, in=180]    (280:5.3)
            to[out=0, in=-45]      (-30:4)
            to[out=180-45, in=-90] (0:3) -- cycle;
\draw[->] (50:4.2) -- +(30:1) node[right] {$\Omega$};
\draw[<-] (85:5) -- +(85:1) node[right] {$u_\varepsilon=0$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes thats what i want but i want to ask you if you can change $\vartheta_\varepsilon$ and put $v_\varepsilon$. And can you send it to me as a pdf to my mail?

Comment: I edited the answer to add the documentclass so that it is compilable now. I also changed the formula as requested. Do you have any problem compiling it?

Comment: Ok thank you, yes i have a problem in compiling all the tikz programs or drawing thats why i ask if you can send to me the pdf

Comment: This answer, unlike other answers for other of your questions, do not require `hobby` nor any other non-standard package. It should compile right out of the box. Which problem do you have?

Comment: tnank you very much, it compile, and yes i have a problem usually with the hobby. @JLDiaz